# Is it possible to transfer schools in the middle of a Master's program?

Tags: graduate-school, thesis, advisor, united-states, transfer-student

I entered my university a year ago. I am enrolled in the master's thesis program. I wanted to do a thesis  , but none of the faculty in my department who do fluid dynamics have an opening for a new researcher in their group. It seems I wont be able to find a thesis advisor in my subfield.
What's my best option in this situation?
is it possible to transfer schools a year in?

Comment: It depends where you are (geographically - i.e., what country you are from), and the policies of the university.

Comment: I'm in the United States.